# HTML issue, Image/links not working

Tags: html

I am just starting out with HTML, and have never coded before. I am trying to create a basic website, with links and pictures and they are not working.

```
<a href=“https://google.com">link please work</a>
```

this is what I get when I click the link.

```
file:///Users/Jessicadotson0012/Desktop/untitled%20folder/%E2%80%9Chttps://google.com%22
```

How do I get it to take me to the link I put?

Secondly, I am trying to get a picture to show up, this is what code I have written:

```
<p> <img src=“>image.jpg” width="100" height="80" alt="my pic"> </p>
```

I have checked to make sure the picture is in the same folder and is the right picture name, but no matter what, the picture only pops up as an image icon, and not the actual picture.

Comment: Why is there a `>` sign in `“>image.jpg”`?

Comment: What editor are you using for your code? If you just copied and pasted your code, take a look at the link. `"` and `“` are different.

Comment: I tried it without this and with it, as I saw two different people try it both ways, and both didn't work for me. I just tried it without it and it wasn't working still.

Comment: Use `<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link please work</a>` and `<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="80" alt="my pic">`. Let's see if that works.

Comment: Also, JasonB, i am just using TextEdit on mac, and how do you get the other type of quotation? I was looking for that but unsure of how to get it.

Comment: Don't use TextEdit... get something like [Brackets](http://brackets.io). IDEs are thought to make sure stuff like this doesn't happen. There are plenty more, but Brackets is my personal favorite for web development.

Comment: Okay, I copied and pasted what you wrote Zeke, and they worked, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, Jessica. What I said is pretty much what Khan answered, so you can accept his answer. No need for me to add another one. Also, use `@` to mention people, that's how we get notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
<a href="https://google.com">link please work</a>
```

Second:

```
<p> <img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="80" alt="my pic"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in your link

```
<a href=“https://google.com">link please work</a>
```

inverted commas are not same. It is recommended to keep links between double inverted commas.

Second, in your image tag

```
<p> <img src=“>image.jpg” width="100" height="80" alt="my pic"> </p>
```

also I think there's problem with inverted commas and there is unnecessary '>' symbol inside src attribute. So it should go like this:

```
<p> <img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="80" alt="my pic"> </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Appreciate that!